# UIBarButtonItem in UiToolbar not responding to touch, only in ios7 portrait mode

Tags: ipad, cocoa-touch, ios7, interface-builder, uibarbuttonitem

I'm updating an existing app for iOS7. The app uses a UIToolbar with two UIBarButtonItem's, one on the left, the other on the right.

The left UIBarButtonItem works as expected. The right UIBarButtonItem does also, *except* in landscape orientation on iOS7. It works fine in iOS6 (all orientations), and in portrait mode (only) in iOS7. I'm seeing this in both the simulator and on my iPad mini.

The button is obviously correctly bound to a segue (since it usually works), and I have confirmed that it is enabled even when it is not working. (My view controller has an update timer, and I log the state on every tick.)

Has anybody else seen something like this? Any ideas?

TIA,
Doug K;

Comment: Are you testing it with same screen size on ios6 and ios7??

Comment: Sorry, missed the question. I just went back to this code base this week and the problem disappeared as mysteriously as it appeared.